# Django not loading 'extends' template in production

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-templates, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm pretty new to Python/Django, but I'm trying to publish an app in AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it's not finding *some* of the templates.

When I request http://www.example.com/path, it throws an error: `TemplateDoesNotExist at /path`

And it says:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /opt/python/bundle/5/app/src/app_name/templates/app_name/tmpl.djhtml, error at line 1

1   {% extends 'app_name/base.djhtml ' %}
2   ...
```

So, it loads the main template, but it doesn't load the one specified with `extends`. What's worse, it says:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
...
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/opt/python/bundle/5/app/src/app_name/templates/app_name/base.djhtml (Source does not exist)
```

If I connect via SSH to the server, the file DOES exist! It also works in my machine in Windows.

If I do an `ls -hal` in that directory, the permissions are the same for both files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 wsgi root  512 Oct 21 17:18 tmpl.djhtml
-rw-r--r-- 1 wsgi root 3.0K Oct 21 17:18 base.djhtml
```

The TEMPLATES settings are as follows:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\','/'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! After a day of trying different things, but just 5 minutes after I posted the question.

The problem was here:

```
{% extends 'app_name/base.djhtml ' %}
```

There's an extra space after the file name. The correct one, obviously is:

```
{% extends 'app_name/base.djhtml' %}
```

That doesn't seem to matter in Windows, but it does in Linux!